# Copying User Profile to Default Profile in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, profile, robocopy

I'm trying to find a way using, hopefully, a batch file to copy a modified user profile to the default user profile so that any user that logs in to the computer will adopt the profile setup. We're using a utility called pGina to call the default profile for a user logged in through a RADIUS server, as opposed to having the user log in to the domain directly. Currently, we're trying to use robocopy for this.

```
cd C:\Users\
rmdir Default /s /q
robocopy /COPY:DAT /R:5 /E C:\Users\user1 C:\Users\Default
pause
```

Does anyone have any idea how to successfully copy the profile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I [found](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/64605-copy-admin-profile-to-default-user/) when searching for an answer to your problem

```
rem delete old Default User profile
RD /s /q "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User"

rem copy current user profile to default user profile
xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\*.*" "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User" /e /c /I /H /R /K /Y 
rem delete non-need some files 
del /f /q "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User\*.*" 
rem set default attributes
attrib +h "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User"

rem registry trick
rem no directly copy locked ntuser.dat file
rem use reg tools to save current user registry to file
reg save HKCU "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User\ntuser.dat"
rem set default attributes to hive file  
attrib +H +S "%systemdrive%\Profiles\Default User\ntuser.dat"
```